# TFS Work Item Tab Visiblity

Tags: tfs

While customizing a TFS work item, is it possible to display/hide a tab control based on the value of another control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, there is no straight forward way of accomplishing this.  One possibility would be to write a custom control, but that does not meet the needs presented to me.

In my situation, I'm working on a customized Requirement work item that also has fields from CaliberRM.  Some of these fields are only applicable to certain types of requirements.  The solution I used was to use the WhenNot rule on the fields that should only be available for certain types of requirements.  That rule has the Empty and ReadOnly rules associated with.  What happens now, if the applicable requirement type is selected then the fields are available; otherwise the fields are not available for input and are emptied out.

Note: One other thing you can do is use the When rule to specify fields that are required based upon the selection of another field.  Works like a charm.