# How can I remove the "Links" tab in the TFS 2018 work item forms?

Tags: tfs

On the MS website there is an instruction how to customize the form data of the "Details" tab:

[image: image Details tab]

But how to customize (and remove) the tab itself?

[image: image Links tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot remove the build-in tabs.

Generally, we just need to remove the `control` element in Layout, then the filed will be disappeared in the work item form.

But based on my test, we cannot remove the **Tab** control for the specific WIT definition file (xml), it will automatically add the control element during the importing action eventhough you removed it before. ([Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits))

We can only custome the extension to show or hide the tab there. See [Add extensions in work item form via work item type definition xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/configure-workitemform-extensions) for details.

***For example:***

To show a tab in work item form, just add an extension tag below the "Work Item Extensions" section

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Id="example.color-control-dev" />
</Extensions>
```

Remove the extension tag to hide the tab.

Similar thread for your reference : [TFS Work Item Tab Visiblity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905082/tfs-work-item-tab-visiblity)

[image]